# how can i use web3.eth.getCode() on html

Tags: solidity, web3js

I want to use `web3.eth.getCode()` on html.

So I use this code on my html:

```
<script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js ">
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    }
    else {
        // Set the provider you want from Web3.providers
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    }
</script>
```

When I use `alert(web3.version.api)`,
it returns 0.20.3

But when I use `alert(web3.eth.getCode("0xd5677cf67b5aa051bb40496e68ad359eb97cfbf8"))`, it doesn't work.

Did I forget something about gas or something else?

Please give me some advice on how to handle a situation like this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You likely need to wait for the query to actually return data by using the promise/callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely because you are not using an Error First Callback, which [allows for Asynchronous requests](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#using-callbacks). This is [required by Metamask](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client), and you will get an error that looks like this if you try to simply make a synchronous call:

> Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods
>   like eth_getCode without a callback parameter. See
>   https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client
>   for details.

To fix this, you can change your pseudo-code into:

```
web3.eth.getCode("0xd5677cf67b5aa051bb40496e68ad359eb97cfbf8", function(error, result) {
    if(!error) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

You can see it working end to end here: https://jsfiddle.net/jx7dunLy/

(I updated the contract address to one that has a value)

```
<script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js "></script>

<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Web3 Detected! ' + web3.currentProvider.constructor.name)
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        console.log('No Web3 Detected... using HTTP Provider')
        window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/<APIKEY>"));
    }

        getCode();
})

function getCode() {
    var code = web3.eth.getCode("0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52", function(error, result) {
    if(!error) {
        alert(result);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: This actually helps me to solve the problem. Thanks!